# Bash: Differentiate between files and directories with wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I have a couple of files in my working directory and I want to print all of the textual files, the problem is in my WD are also directories. This means, when I type:

```
cat *
```

The output is:

```
9 Tom Grapes 28
10 Ben Lemon 21
11 Paul Lime 37

Next cool file

cat: yang: Is a directory
cat: ying: Is a directory
```

I want to remove these 'error-messages', so I tried:

```
cat *[!/]
```

But it just returns:

```
cat: '*[!/]': No such file or directory
```

But the other way around:

```
cat */
```

prints only:

```
cat: yang: Is a directory
cat: ying: Is a directory
```

Does this mean everything even files end with a slash? If yes, is there a way to differentiate between files and directories? If not, why does this wild card not work?

**PS: I'm using Linux**

Comment: A note aside: You are using bash, but if you are free to choose the shell, you might consider using Zsh. Several problems, which are difficult to solve in bash, are easy (though sometimes look a bit cryptic) in Zsh. In your case, the Zsh command would be `cat *(^/)`. The expression in parenthesis says "no directories". Like the bash counterpart, this would give an error if there are no plain files. If you want that cat in this case simply doesn't write anything, you would do `cat *(N^/) /dev/null`. The *N* means: Replace the glob pattern by an empty string, if no files match.

Answer (score 4):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} +
```

**Edit:**

To ignore hidden files

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[!.]*' -exec cat {} +
```

Reference: [Exclude hidden files when searching with Unix/Linux find?](https://superuser.com/a/999448)

Comment: Of course you can use `find` for that. But aren't you using a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Comment: Also a note: This finds hidden files. This might be what you want, it might not be.

Comment: @chw21 good point about hidden files, which can be avoided by adding ` -not -path './.*'` ... on using `find` it is a command built to search for files, so I don't think it is wrong tool to use here

Comment: Among Unix tools, `find` is less a sledgehammer and more a Swiss army knife.

Answer (score 2):

Any expression like `*` only refers to the file name itself, not the type. Unless you have a distinct naming convention (e.g. files all have an extension, directories never do) it will be hard to distinguish between files and directories based on their name.

The trailing `/` is not part of the name.

Quick and dirty solution:

```
cat * 2>/dev/null
```

This addition just suppresses all error messages. (Actually, it re-routes them to the void.)

If I wanted to do it properly, this would be my first step. It might not be the best solution, but it goes through all entries in the directory, checks whether it's a file, and only `cat` those.

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        cat $f
    fi
done
```

Which can be written in one line:

```
for f in *; do if [[ -f $f ]]; then cat $f; fi; done
```

Maybe someone else here has a better idea.

Comment: It works but I don't know why, thanks anyway. I guess I'll enlarge upon bash and come back to this answer when I got some know-how. But can you explain me, why my suggested command did not work?

Comment: I've edited my answer to elaborate more on what I do.

Comment: I'll give you a brief example I have 3 files: 'file1','file2','file3'. In order to get 'file3' you can use `cat *[3]` to get the opposite of that you can use `cat *[!3]`, with the first command you'll get 'file3' with the second you'll get 'file1' and 'file2'. Back to my question: `cat */` will only return errors, because only directories were referenced. Now vice versa: to reference only 'not-directories'(=files) I'll use `cat *[!/]`, but this does strangely not work. That's my point, I hope its better understandable now.

Comment: Okay, you've found the edges of my `bash` skills. But either of my solutions should work, and you can also use @sp-asic 's idea of using `find` ;)

Comment: Okay, that's weird. This little problem implies such an effort. I thought it would be handled within seconds, but.. yeah. Thanks for your replies!